# PHP Gettext Not Working

Tags: php, locale, gettext

Here's my `./locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po` file:

```
msgid "NO GOOD"
msgstr "IT WORKED!"
```

Command used to generate the .mo file:

```
$ msgfmt -o locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po
```

My PHP file (being run via CLI, for testing purposes, as root).

```
<?php 
    bindtextdomain('messages','./locale');
    textdomain('messages');
    setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'fr');
    echo gettext("NO GOOD");
```

Here's my output:

```
$ NO GOOD
```

PHPInfo:

```
GetText Support => enabled
```

Any ideas why this might not work?

Comment: Hint when working with gettext, always check the function return values.

Comment: There are a couple of reasons why this might not work. For starters, you'll need to specify the charset of your MO file using `bind_textdomain_codeset()`. You'll also need to make sure that the appropriate locale file is installed in your system (assuming you're using a Linux-based server), *and also that this locale file has the correct charset*. Have a look at this article for more details: https://blog.terresquall.com/2020/09/troubleshooting-php-gettext/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out the reason it wasn't working is the locale I choose has to be a recognized one by the system.

In my case, `fr` is not a valid locale, I had to pick `fr_FR.UTF-8` which the system recognizes...

Comment: FYI, the `setlocale()` function will return `false` if the locale you specified was not recognized.
`Returns the new current locale, or FALSE if the locale functionality is not implemented on your platform, the specified locale does not exist or the category name is invalid.`

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure language is supported
2. install gettext and enable it in php.ini
3. check correct format of po (it should have the headers)
4. make sure mbstring.internalcoding is set to UTF-8  ()uncomment for utf8 in php.ini)
5. restart php and web server